# cannot find symbol with reference variable

Tags: java

There are two classes the game and GameHelper,the compiler shows two errors which are

game.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
                GameHelper helper=new GameHelper();
                ^
      symbol:   class GameHelper
  location: class game
game.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
                GameHelper helper=new GameHelper();
                                      ^
  symbol:   class GameHelper
  location: class game
  2 errors

The game class

```
class game
{
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    String g;
    sinkdot one=new sinkdot();
    GameHelper helper=new GameHelper();
    int randnum=(int)(Math.random()*7);
    int[] locs={randnum,randnum+1,randnum+2};
    int guesscount=0;
    one.locationsetter(locs);
    boolean isAlive=true;
    while(isAlive==true)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter your guess");
        g=helper.getUserInput("Enter a number");
        guesscount=guesscount+1;
        String returnval=one.checkyourself(g);
        System.out.println(returnval);
        if(returnval.equals("Kill"))
        {
            isAlive=false;
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Number of attempts are"+guesscount);
}
}
```

The GameHelper class

```
import java.io.*;
public class GameHelper{
public String getUserInput(String prompt){
    String inputLine=null;
    System.out.print(prompt+" ");
    try{
        BufferedReader is=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        inputLine=is.readLine();
        if(inputLine.length()==0){
        return null;
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("IOException:"+e);
        }
        return inputLine;
    }
}
}
```

I'm compiling it with javac game.java line.There are no error in sinkdot class so i didn't mention it.

Comment: How are you compiling these classes?

Comment: i'm compiling it with javac game.java line

Comment: You need also to include the GameHelper.java file. All your classes should start with upper case letters. e.g. Game instead of game

Comment: Check the classes should all be in the same package (for this error to resolve in your question), and correct access modifier should be in place.

Comment: Indeed. `javac *.java` might do the trick. Or you can compile `GameHelper` first and, use the compiler's class search path to find it; something like `javac -classpath . game.java`. And yes, while the compiler doesn't (usually) care about letter case, people have gotten used to class names starting with capitals.

Comment: You guys solved it.Thank you guys you are awsome.